# Sites that are "W3C Mark Up Validation" Certified?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, w3c-validation

I'm kind of confused with this...

My Uni's club website policy says that sites have to be w3c markup validated (http://validator.w3.org/). However, when I test out random sites from the web they all seem to fail. Can someone list sites that are valid so I may use them for reference?

Also, can anyone list some good web development tools? I wanted to use Visual Studio but I'm doubting the school supports ASP.NET MVC :P.

Comment: You don't have to design a site in ASP.Net MVC with Visual Studio.  In fact, you can design plain HTML sites in VS, or even PHP sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's unrealistic to require sites to be 100% validated against the W3C, especially if it needs modern functionality. My guess is the sites that your uni hosts are therefore pretty plain in design/functionality. *But obviously your Uni disagrees*, so you have no choice.

I don't know what purpose would be served by finding examples of validated sites; Just validate yours aggressively as you develop/design it.

As for recommending good dev tools, that depends on what your uni *does* support. I use ActiveState Komodo Edit for PHP sites myself, and Visual Studio for ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC sites.